# How do I create togglable tabs in Visual Composer with images in the tab header part?

Tags: html, wordpress, tabs, toggle

I am working in a page right now with Wordpress and Visual Composer/WPBakery Page Builder as the "builder". The thing is:
I am trying to make togglable tabs but with images on the header part of the tabs.

I tried with some code on the tittle tab section but it just works with some text format, like `<strong> <em>` like the following picture:

How it looks on WP w/ VC
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wP7q.png

How it looks on the web
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj4Eh.png

An example of what I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH4Ka.png
is like having icons but with pictures.

I was asking my self if exist any kind of modification or CSS style I can use to modify the content of the tabs header and how can I do it.

Regards